# Is there a connection between the Kernels in Statistics and Linear Algebra?

Tags: data-transformation, terminology, kernel-trick, definition, weights

According to this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/341826/why-the-name-kernel-in-stats-and-ml), the etymology of the terms is related, and Kernel is used to mean the "core" of something. In general it seems to refer to an unchanging transformation at the heart of a maths problem

In linear algebra, a Kernel is the vector space for which a matrix always go to zero.

In statistics, I have seen the term "kernel X" used to describe various types of weighting function.

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(statistics)) indicates that, in statistical analysis, it's considered a [window function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function).

In the case of Linear Algebra, the Kernel vector space could be considered a matrix transformation. Does the same apply to the Kernel in Statistics? Can the weighting function, or window function be considered a transformation?

Comment: FYI: “kernel” has at least two meanings in statistics https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/2500/35989 If you look at Wkipiedia, the word is used in many contexts https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel Words are ambiguous.

Comment: True, but mathematics is so precise in so many ways that it's strange when the words don't follow suit! I take it your comment means that it is a coincidence?

Comment: That's why mathematics has its own (mathematical) language rather than relying on English (or whatever) language.

Comment: I you can't find at least 10 distinct meanings for "kernel" in mathematics, you're [not searching hard enough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel);-).

Comment: the general answer to these questions must be YES, as probability theory is almost an application of functional analysis which includes linear algebra. any concept in statistics has some representation in linear algebra. the nuance is that you may name something in stats while its representation in linear algebra may have a different name. in case of Kernel at least in some contexts the term refers to mirroring concepts in stats and linear algebra. moreover Kernel also refers to a similar concept in machine learning domain too, see e.g. "kernel trick" in SVM

Comment: @Aksakal The extreme reduction of statistics to linear algebra suggested in that comment flies in the face of much of the statistical literature, especially any part of it concerned with modeling nonlinear phenomena.  It also neglects the important fact that statistics is not mathematics: the math is used to help us understand and develop the statistical concepts but it is not the same thing.

Comment: @whuber, that's why I wrote *functional analysis* to cover everything, though a lot of stats mirrors linear algebra. I agree though that theory of probabilities is not a simple application of math, thus *almost* qualifier in my comment

Comment: @Aksakal I suppose you could roll up most of mathematics under the functional analysis flag -- at which point calling something an application of functional analysis isn't telling us anything.